# WebAPI not Enabling CORS - 404 Not Found on OPTIONS

Tags: c#, reactjs, asp.net, cors, webapi

I am using web api with C# and calling it from a React app.
From the front end:

```
          const resp = await axios.post("http://localhost:26594/api/Member/Login", {
  member: user,
  sessionid,
});
```

In the web api I have installed:
[image]

In the WebAPIConfig.cs I have added:

```
     var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");
        config.EnableCors(cors);
```

But when I try to call it I receive:
[image]
[image]

I then tried to add the web.config:

```
<httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
          <!-- Adding the following custom HttpHeader 
             will help prevent CORS from stopping the Request-->
          <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
      </customHeaders>
  </httpProtocol>
```

and

```
<remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
    <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
    <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
```

But nothing worked!

**NOTE: I tried one GET method and working normally. POST method is not working.**

Comment: The EnableCorsAttribute goes on your endpoints

Comment: @DanielA.White Can you please explain>

Comment: Instead of verb="*", I would try listing all of the allowed verbs: verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" or whatever subset you want to allow.

Comment: @TGnat where do you mean?

Comment: @DanielA.White I have added the attribute on the end point, but it did not work

Comment: @TGnat Did not wok

Comment: @HasanShouman What authentication method you are using? Preflight requests (OPTIONS) do not send auth info to the server. So, you need to enable Anonymous Auth in addition to WinAuth.

Comment: @ChinmayT I am not using any auth. I have the [AllowAnonymous] on the endpoint I am calling.

Comment: i used to have this issue have you done a setupProxy.js file?

Answer (score 1):

**SOLVED**.

It turned out that there is a setting in the IIS that is disallowing the OPTIONS verb.

To check, open IIS, if you have your website listed click it, or click "Default Web Site".
Under the IIS section click "Request Filtering".

If you see empty list then all verbs are allowed.
Else if you see the verb and next to it "False" then it is not allowed. So remove it from the list to allow it.

**NOTE: If your API is not allowing CORS then you will receive 405 not allowed.
If the error from IIS as mentioned above, you will receive 404 not found.**